# Remove outer double quotation marks from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list called data which I converted from pandas Dataframe with this syntax `df.annotations.values.tolist()` and I am trying to remove the outer double quotations from it which is a list of tuples. Is there any simple way I could do it?

From

```
["('Jack', {'entities': [(0, 12, 'PERSON')]})",
 "('Alba', {'entities': [(0, 15, 'PERSON')]})",
 "('Brandy at town', {'entities': [(0, 15, 'PERSON')]})",
 "('Hailey', {'entities': [(0, 10, 'PERSON')]})"]
```

to

```
[('Jack', {'entities': [(0, 12, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Alba', {'entities': [(0, 15, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Brandy at town', {'entities': [(0, 15, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Hailey', {'entities': [(0, 10, 'PERSON')]})]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
out = list(map(ast.literal_eval, lst))
```

as a list comprehension:

```
out = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in lst]
```

Output:

```
[('Jack', {'entities': [(0, 12, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Alba', {'entities': [(0, 15, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Brandy at town', {'entities': [(0, 15, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Hailey', {'entities': [(0, 10, 'PERSON')]})]
```